# pandas pivot csv file containing sales data based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a requirement where I need to pivot the data for sales and number of units sold each year.

My input data looks like this:[image]

My approach so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
dfg=pd.read_csv("document.csv")
dfg
lst=dfg.columns.tolist()  # converting dataframe columns to list
lst

import numpy as np

datadict={}

sales_values=[]
units_values=[]

sales_year_lst=[]
units_year_lst=[]

for ln in lst:

    if re.match(r"\d{4}\_sales", ln):
        match = re.search('\d{4}', ln)
        year=match.group(0)
        sales_year_lst.append(year)
        sales_values.append(dfg[ln].values)
        datadict['sales_year']=sales_year_lst
        datadict['sales']=sales_values

    elif re.match(r"\d{4}\_units_sold", ln):
        match = re.search('\d{4}', ln)
        year=match.group(0)
        units_year_lst.append(year)
        units_values.append(dfg[ln].values)
        datadict['units_year']=units_year_lst
        datadict['units']=units_values

    # created a data dictionary to store the year value, sales and 
    #  units values respectively

df=pd.DataFrame(datadict)
df
# created a dataframe from the dictionary

dff=df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series)
                         .stack()
                         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        ).rename_axis('month').reset_index()


dfk=dff[["sales_year","sales","units"]]

dfgh = dfg[dfg.columns.drop(list(dfg.filter(regex='\d{4}')))]
frames = [dfgh,dfk]

result = pd.concat(frames,axis=1,join='outer')
result.fillna(method='ffill')
```

The output which I'm getting is something like this:
[image]

After concatenating the dataframes, what fillna is doing is it's taking the last column value which is something I don't want.

My expected output is something like this:

[image]

I'm new to python and I'm not getting any idea on how to approach further. I'm stuck badly, any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit :

> I need to split the column based on 'year' in the column name. The requirement is such that the search has to be based on a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way using multiindexing of columns with `stack` to reshape the dataframe:

Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A']*2+['B']*2,'pack':['1g','500mg','1g','500mg'],'2017_sales':[500,600,1200,400],'2018_sales':[300,500,800,200],
                  '2017_units_sold':[50,60,120,40],'2018_units_sold':[30,50,80,20]})

   2017_sales  2017_units_sold  2018_sales  2018_units_sold name   pack
0         500               50         300               30    A     1g
1         600               60         500               50    A  500mg
2        1200              120         800               80    B     1g
3         400               40         200               20    B  500mg
```

Now, use the following:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['name','pack'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', 1, expand=True) #creating multiindex with split
df_out = df1.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'year'})
df_out
```

Output:

```
  name   pack  year  sales  units_sold
0    A     1g  2017    500          50
1    A     1g  2018    300          30
2    A  500mg  2017    600          60
3    A  500mg  2018    500          50
4    B     1g  2017   1200         120
5    B     1g  2018    800          80
6    B  500mg  2017    400          40
7    B  500mg  2018    200          20
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for your answer, however I need to split the column based on 'year' in the column name. It has to be a regular expression. Your solution works perfectly in case if it's needed to split the column name based on underscore. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well if your column names are always. year then underscore this will work.

Comment: @nishantambastha Did you want to try somethting like this instead? `df.columns.str.extractall(r'(\d+)|(\w+)').apply(lambda x: x.dropna().sum(level=0))`

Comment: The only thing which is sure is that the column name will have a year, the other value could succeed or precede. That's why the requirement is to search based on year or split based on year.

Comment: df.columns.str.extractall(r'(\d+)|(\w+)').apply(lambda x: x.dropna().sum(level=0))

This isn't giving the result as the expected output. I thank you really for helping me out on this though :)

Comment: Is there any other way around?

Comment: Can you give data not yielding expected results and what the expected results from these data are?